# How to get objects from array of objects for given key

Tags: objective-c, arrays, key

I get rows from database into array. And then for example I have in these rows fields like ´ID´,´Section´. Is it possible to get all ID´s for chosen section from array without loops using some operators?
For Instance

1 a
 2 b
 2 a
 3 a
 4 b

and then for section 'a' I'd like to get [1,2,3]

Comment: What type has your database?

Comment: It is MySql. Normal rows..

Comment: Each row is a NSDictionary in my Array

Answer (score 0):

If your database is an `Array` of `Tuples` you can do something like this:

```
let database: [(Int, String)] = [(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (2, "a"), (3, "a"), (4, "b")]

let aNumbers = database.filter{ $0.1 == "a" }.map{ $0.0 }
```

Or with swift 2:

```
let aNumbers = database.flatMap{ $0.1 == "a" ? $0.0 : nil }
```

Comment: How about Objective-C? This is what the questioner is interested in (according to tagging)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I thought this was a swift question. Should I delete it?

Comment: No, I don't think you should delete it, but it would be nice if you added Objective-C solution

Comment: Would be nice if the answer was in Objective-C.